# Integer solution constraint for scipy.optimize.differential_evolution?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, differential-evolution

I am trying to use the [scipy.optimize.differential_evolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html) optimizer in my program. But *I need the solution to be of only integers*...

Right now the solution (the **attribute x of scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult**) always looks something like this:

```
[3.56932195, 1.69611735, 8.67970522, 9.69922539, 6.43961603, 3.3292928 , 2.32741226]
```

But I need all the elements in the solution to be integers, e.g.:

```
[6, 6, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3]
```

Is there any way to enforce this? Or is there any other/better suited package I could use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scipy version 1.9 `differential_evolution` will gain an `integrality` keyword that will do exactly what you want, without problem modification. In the meantime you can simply round all the parameter values to integers, e.g. `np.round`, in your objective function. This approach works with and without constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a mixed integer programming solver.

Unless your constraint matrix is unimodular, you cannot ensure an integer solution without a MIP solver.

By saying that all of the solutions need to be integer, you are saying that your problem is non-convex. But you are instead trying to solve a convex problem.

you might want to check out tools such as GLPK and CBC, if your constraints/equations are linear.  If your constraints are nonlinear you need to look into nonlinear integer programming solvers.